# How do you build a webapp?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications

Probably a very stupid and easy question.

I'm new to React but I'm honestly new to software engineering in general.
I'm trying to build a web app, but I have no idea how.
I don't know anything about web apps, except that you should know a bit of HTML, CSS, JS.

Anyway, I went into this link https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html  to create my first React app. I followed the instructions carefully and I now have this tab opened on pc:

[image]

I of course would like to edit the code and start making my app. But how? Where?

Where is this code written? Inside the directory that I used there is still nothing. I looked for "src" or "App.js" on my pc and found nothing. Where is it? Should I download anything else?

I'm a bit lost with this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I actually just managed to find the directory. I’m a computer science major going for my second year, trying to build a summer project. For now I only know how to code in Java and C. I’m trying to teach myself some more things. Thank you anyway!

Comment: That's a different story... I thought that you know much less... Still, there are great courses that will save you time...

Comment: I was in your position with react 3 months back and now I am answering react questions. I also built a great web app. Youtube videos where you can see things in action is the best place. A few lines of code as an answer to your question is not going to do you much good. I suggest following some video tutorials that have github repository as well. The only way to learn is build sample projects and ask SPECIFIC questions here when you get stuck. I recommend this over react as its kind of easier and built upon react - https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app